# load .png from url's in the existing imageview

Tags: android

i seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android), and made how they say.
my app loads and shows .jpg, but don't show .png. He shows empty screen. (tested on versions 4.1 and 4.2)

```
    if (isOnline()) {
            new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewSA))
                    .execute(img);
        } else {
            tv_info.setText("Включите интернет для загрузки");
        }

    }


private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }


    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

    }
```

Comment: You can google and try Picasso library. It's good!

Comment: What is the exact problem are you facing? your code seems fine!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar my app loads and shows files ".jpg", but DON'T SHOW files ".png". when i try to load file .png my imageview is empty(white area). Now i will use [inuversal image laoder](http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-library-in-android) or picasso, and i hope that they will work

Comment: Is your png is opening perfect in imageviewer or browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use universal image loader library instead, so easy to integrate in your code, you can display images from URL to imageView like this

```
imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView);
```

here's a good [example](http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-library-in-android) of using UIL

and the [library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/sample)

good luck ;)

Comment: Thank you! [Universal Image Loader Library In Android](http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-library-in-android) very simple instrument!